# How to change screen by swiping in kivy python

Tags: python, android, kivy

I am trying to change to another screen by swiping the screen. I've tried carousel but it seems that it only works with images, so I've tried detecting a swipe motion and changing the screen after it has been detected.

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.button import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.carousel import Carousel
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup


class HomeScreen(Screen):
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch.x < touch.ox: # this line checks if a left swipe has been detected
            MainApp().change_screen(screen_name="swipedhikr_screen") # calls the method in the main app that changes the screen


class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass


class LabelButton(ButtonBehavior, Label):
    pass


class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    pass


class SwipeDhikrScreen(Screen):
    pass


#def quit_verification():

 #   pop = Popup(title="verification", content=Label(text= "Are you sure?"))


GUI = Builder.load_file("main.kv")


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return GUI

    def change_screen(self, screen_name):
        # get the screen manager from the kv file
        screen_manager = self.root.ids["screen_manager"]
        screen_manager.transition.direction = "up"
        screen_manager.current = screen_name

    def quit_app(self):
        MainApp().stop()




MainApp().run()
```

I got an attribute error: "None type object has no attribute 'ids'"

Comment: You should post a new question, and write up your excellent Youtube solution as the answer! Thankyou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MainApp().change_screen(screen_name="swipedhikr_screen")
```

This line creates a *new* instance of `MainApp`, which doesn't have any widgets and therefore naturally fails when you try to access them.

Use the existing instance of `MainApp`, i.e. the one that you're actually running, via `MainApp.get_running_app()`.

Also you are not correct that Carousel works only with images.

Comment: Thanks you very much it works. Do you know how to use Carouse for screen swiping?

Comment: the direction of the transition is the same as the other transition even though I did ```MainApp.get_running_app().screen_direction = "left"```. It transitions left the first time the app runs but after returning to the home page it's up.  NB: I've changed this line```screen_manager.transition.direction = "up"``` to ```screen_direction = screen_manager.transition.direction```